# Laravel query builder "where"

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel-5

i have the following query

```
select * from (SELECT accident.id,count(*) as cnt from accident left join driver on driver.accident_id = accident.id group by accident.id)alias where cnt = 1
```

and this is my query builder

```
$accidents = DB::table('accident')
        ->leftjoin('driver','accident.id','driver.accident_id')
        ->select(DB::raw('accident.*,count(*) as jumlah_kendaraan'))->groupBy('accident.id')
        ->where('jumlah_kendaraan', $jumlah_kendaraan);
```

i tried to convert it like the above but i got an error says

```
SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR: column "jumlah_kendaraan" does not exist
```

can anyone help me to solve it? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot filter the result of an aggregate function `count()` using where clause, Instead use `having` for this purpose

```
->having('jumlah_kendaraan', $jumlah_kendaraan)
```

Or use your complete expression

```
->havingRaw('count(*) = '.$jumlah_kendaraan)
```

Comment: i replace where with having but i still got the same error sir

Comment: @PinballWizard I have added another clause, Are you sure you got the same error or different error ?

Answer (score 1):

`where clause` can not use alias of group function directly, use

```
->where('count(*)', $jumlah_kendaraan);
```

You can use `having` as well but in case if `having` is not working use like given above.